# The best way to validate data of form in the fullstack web app (Spring boot + React JS)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, validation

I develop fullstack web app using for backend: Spring (boot, MVC, Data JPA) and for frontend I'm using ReactJS.
In during of develop I got some questions about data validation. I've tried to do maximum validation on frontend that don't make excess requests to backend (min/max length of inputs, not empty and some patterns for specific inputs), but there are some validations need to check on backend (existing same login for example), and it's works perfect.
But I check data again before putting data to database for exact certainty, using annotations on my POJO class like this:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 5, max = 30)
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-z0-9_-]*$")
@Column(name = "login")
private String login;
```

I have duplicate values for validate, the first on the frontend, and the second on the backend. And I don't sure if it's good practics, because if I change validation constrains on frontend or backend I would have to manually change on the second part.

How to set validation constrains in the one place that use it for backend and frontend?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: Validating in the backend is a **must**, since front-end validation can be bypassed by the user. I think it's a good idea to validate on both backend & frontend, though it does involved duplication.